# How to play a full album starting from unity music lens?

Tags: unity, music

if I search form music in my Unity music lens I get as results single tracks (which get played by rhythmbox if I click on them) and albums which don't get played if I click on them.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Having the same issue... :( Did you ever find anything else about this?  Bug report even?

Comment: Just for completeness/usefulness of this question which was version before?

Answer (score 1):

Now fixed with the last update.